# Easy Node Authentication: Google

Tags: node.js, passport.js, passport-google-oauth2

I am trying to login with google to my application, but it shows an error like shown below,

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?response_type=code&redirect_ur…d=410427634474-u3tpasmj4r80s6v20o54s85fikhotl79.apps.googleusercontent.com. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.`

I have tried something like below

### app.js

```
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID        : config.googleAuth.clientID,
    clientSecret    : config.googleAuth.clientSecret,
    callbackURL     : config.googleAuth.callbackURL
},
function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
   User.findOrCreate({ googleId: profile.id }, function (err, user) {
     return done(err, user);
   });
}
));


router.get('/pages/auth/loginWithGoogle',
    passport.authenticate('google', { scope: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login'] }));

router.get('/auth/google/callback',
passport.authenticate('google', {
   successRedirect : '/invite-friends',
   failureRedirect : '/pages/auth/login'
}));
```

Comment: The error occured when you're using ajax to authorize

Comment: How to fix this problem? could you please help me?

Comment: Use hyperlink `<a href="/pages/auth/loginWithGoogle">Google</a>`, that opens link as page, not through ajax

Comment: But I am using MVC architecture. Below code shows my html and controller. `<md-button class="md-raised google" ng-click="vm.loginWithGoogle();">
                </md-button>` and my controller is  `vm.loginWithGoogle = function(userData){
   $http({
    url: 'http://192.168.2.8:7200/api/pages/auth/loginWithGoogle',
    method: 'GET'
   }).then(function(res){
    
     console.log("successfully");
    
   }, function(error){
    console.log(error);
    alert(error.data);
   });
  };`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$http()` it will send an ajax request, that wont work

The code below opens url in a new window, then if user authorized and everything is ok it will redirect main page to `/invite-friends`

```
    vm.loginWithGoogle = function(){
        var win = window.open('/api/pages/auth/loginWithGoogle', "windowname1", 'width=800, height=600'); 
        var REDIRECT = 'callback';

        var pollTimer   =   window.setInterval(function() { 
            try {
                if (win.document.URL.indexOf(REDIRECT) != -1) {
                    window.clearInterval(pollTimer);
                    window.location = window.location.origin + '/invite-friends';
                    win.close();
                }
            } catch(e) {
            }
        }, 100);
    }
```

or use it to open url in a current page:

```
vm.loginWithGoogle = function(){
    location.href = '/api/pages/auth/loginWithGoogle';
}
```

Comment: it will open window and come back for my app  home page but it will not going to google authentication page or not ask anything.

Comment: maybe because of you already allowed to GoogleApp for using your user data

Comment: You allow to use your data only when youre authorizing first time

Comment: do your page redirects?

Comment: And one more thing i used two ports here. One for API server and one for client. Is there any problem with that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118524/discussion-between-kevin-and-tilekbekov-yrysbek).